# Grab first successful pair from a list of maps

Tags: functional-programming, scala, optional

I have a function that parses geographic coordinates through a list of different providers. In this case I want to look up two addresses. The main problem of this question is - given a List of of Geocode Service -> Resolved Address mappings, find the first successful pair that has a valid resolved address.

So each address results in a map(provider -> result). I'm given a list of them, and need to find the a successful pair from the list e.g provider1 from the first address and provider1 from the second address. I can't compare the resolved addresses if the providers do not match.

For example, the best scenario is that the addresses are perfect. I can use the head map entry of the first address and query the map entry for the second address. Then compare their values. However, it's rarely that simple.

I started out with a foldLeft, but I feel that can be inefficient if it matches successfully immediately.

```
val result: List[Map[GeoProviders.GeoProvider, Either[GeoCodeErrors.GeocodeError, PostalAddress]]]
                  result match {
                    case firstAddressOption :: secondAddressOption :: Nil => {
                      firstAddressOption.foldLeft[Option[Double]](None)((result, address1: (GeoProvider, Either[GeocodeError, PostalAddress])) => {
                        result match {
                          case Some(_) => result
                          case None =>
                            val address2 = secondAddressOption.get(address1._1)
                            (address1._2, address2) match {
                              case  (Right(successAddr1), Some(Right(successAddr2))) => {
                                (successAddr1.coordinates, successAddr2.coordinates) match {
                                  case (Some(firstCoord), Some(secondCoord)) => {
                                    Some(haversineDistance((firstCoord.latitude, firstCoord.longitude), (secondCoord.latitude, secondCoord.longitude)))
                                  }
                                  case _ => None
                                }
                              }
                            }
                        }
                      })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to avoid folding over an entire map, something like:

```
map1.find {
  case (k, Right(addr1)) =>
    map2.get(k) match {
      case Some(Right(addr2)) => true
      case _ => false
    }
  case _ => false
} match {
  case Some((k, Right(addr1))) =>
    map2.get(k) match {case Some(Right(addr2)) => Some(haversineDistance(addr1, addr2))}
  case _ => None
}
```

(I renamed `first/secondAddressOption` to `map1/map2` to save some typing)

An alternative approach, which doesn't necessarily improve performance but does make the code shorter and more reusable, is to create a method that combines two maps by key:

```
def combineMaps[K, V](map1: Map[K, V], map2: Map[K, V]): Map[K, List[V]] =
  // To improve performance, compare the sizes of map1 and map2
  // and fold over the smaller map.
  map1.foldLeft(map2.mapValues(List(_))) {
    case (map2, (k, x)) => map2.updated(k, x :: map2.get(k).toList.flatten)
  }
```

Then use `collectFirst` on the combined map:

```
combineMaps(map1, map2).collectFirst {
  case (_, Right(addr1) :: Right(addr2) :: Nil) => haversineDistance(addr1, addr2)
}
```